# SQL: Select Different column depending on other table column value

Tags: mysql, sql

I am quite new in SQL. Currently, I wrote like this to select different column depending on other table column value.

```
select 
IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Language WHERE PSID=53435 and Language='zg')>0,
AddressZG,Address) as Address
 from Classes where ID = 1
```

I need to write multiple checking in that (`Language='uni')` and `Language='en')`). How can I write?

Currently, I wrote like this to support multiple if-else but look like it is not correct way.

```
select 
IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Language WHERE PSID=3593031830770623 and Language='zg')>0,
AddressZG,(select 
IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Language WHERE PSID=3593031830770623 and Language='uni')>0,
Address,Address) as Address
 from Classes where ID = 1)) as Address
 from Classes where ID = 1
```

How shall I write multiple if-else to select different column depending on other table column value?

Comment: Please tag your RDBMS.

Comment: Sample data would help.  What tables do the columns come from?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CASE` instead of `IF`:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Language WHERE PSID=3593031830770623 and Language='zg') > 0 THEN AdressZG
       WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Language WHERE PSID=3593031830770623 and Language='uni') > 0 THEN Address
       ELSE Address
  END AS Address
FROM Classes WHERE ID = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do what you want more directly using `join` and `group by`.  I *think* the logic you want is:

```
select coalesce(max( case when language = 'zg' then c.addresszg end),
                max( case when language = 'uni' then c.addressuni end),
                max(address)
               )
from classes c left join
     Language l
     on l.PSID = 53435
where c.id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

COUNT -> EXISTS

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Language WHERE PSID=3593031830770623 and Language='zg') THEN AdressZG
       WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Language WHERE PSID=3593031830770623 and Language='uni') THEN Address
       ELSE Address
  END AS Address
FROM Classes WHERE ID = 1
```